# NSString converting percentage characters

Tags: iphone, url, encode

I have an NSString *str = @"T%B3%C3%83";

where %C3 represents A with an umlut (I think), %B3 an m, %83 a superscript 3...

What is the best way to convert these percentages into the actual characters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `-stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` method in NSString.
P.S. However I don't know what encoding you must use to get results you've mentioned in your question (are you sure they're correct?)